# Django - Unsupported operand type(s) for decimal and method

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add two values (one from a method and one from a field) in my Django models.py.

```
class Object(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField()
    def scaled_value(self):
        scaled_val = float(self.value) * 3
        return scaled_val
    def add_val_and_scaled_val(self):
        sum = self.scaled_value + self.value
        return sum
```

When I try to get the value of the sum from the '`add_val_and_scaled_val`' method in my template like this `{% Object.add_val_and_scaled_val %}` then I get the TypeError...

```
TypeError at /objects/detail/object-12345678/
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instancemethod' and 'Decimal'
```

The instancemethod which the error refers to (`self.scaled_value`) should return a decimal value should it not? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`scaled_value` is a method, you need to call it in your calculation not just refer to it.

```
sum = self.scaled_value() + self.value
```

(Although I'm not sure of the point of any of this code. x*3 + x just equals x*4, no?)

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly! And this code is just a snippet of what I'm trying to do and is just like that for simplicity for readers.

Answer (score 0):

> The instancemethod which the error refers to (self.scaled_value) should return a decimal value should it not

```
def scaled_value(self):
    scaled_val = float(self.value) * 3
    return scaled_val
```

No it shouldn't because in `scaled_value` you explicity convert to a `float`

Also you need to change this code

```
def add_val_and_scaled_val(self):
    sum = self.scaled_value() + self.value # you had self.scaled_value
    return sum
```

You should reconsider adding `float` and `Decimal` however

Lastly, would recommend against shadowing the builtin `sum` function with `sum = ...`